# SQL Server update column

Tags: database, mssql-jdbc

I have a table A with columns of data type `Varchar` and columns name consists of:

```
MatricNo
Email
Name
Remarks
```

How can I update only one of the email if one MatricNo have more than one email?

If I am using below SQL statement I get a message 'No row affected'

```
UPDATE A  
SET  Email = @usermail   --abc@gmail.com(to be update)
    ,Name = @full_name  --abc
    ,Remarks = @remarks --test`
WHERE 
   MatricNo = @MatricNo --123456
   AND (Email = @Email) --abc123@
```

Comment: Hello sir can you please clarify your question with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can update any attribute on the basis of primary key or unique key only.

Comment: MatricNo and Email is primary key. How to update one of the email? Where condition cannot only MatricNo.